# msmtp and multiple websites

Tags: php, email, nginx, smtp

I have a VPS with linode where i'm running 5 websites, some of them are basic php website and some of them are wordpress websites.

I use nginx;

```
#nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
```

with PHP pools for each site;

```
# php5-fpm -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:03:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

I installed some time ago "msmtp"

```
 # cat .msmtp_php 
account gmail
tls on
tls_certcheck on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
auth on
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
user user@domain.com
from noreply@domain.com
password <password>
```

I would like to accomplish the following;
Each domain sends an email from it's own domain.
Basically;

```
domain1.com -> noreply@domain1.com
domain2.com -> noreply@domain2.com
domain3.com -> noreply@domain3.com
```

All the noreply@ emails exist and working just fine.

P.S
Each site is configured to send the emails from the same domain, but since my msmtp is set to a hardcoded domain, it doesn't work.

Please feel free to send any other recommendations.

Comment: Do you do any config inside php for this to work?

Comment: Yes, you might want to google msmtp_php  to find the instructions